# ASP.Net Using Respone.Flush() in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I have HTML report that downloaded to client using this method:

```
Response.Output.Write(stringHTML.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I want to use this method in a loop but the Response.End() method causing the code to break, any ideas how can I acheive this?

Comment: can you tell us more about what it is that your actually doing and why you want it to run in a loop?

Comment: Response.End() will end the request-handling thread. So you can't use it in a loop. Can't you put it outside the loop?

Comment: I have list of contracts, for each one of them I have report. I want the client to click once and then download all reports one after one.

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel, If I will use it outside the loop I will get exception says: 'Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.'

Comment: You can not - what you try to can not happens, find some other way to send multiple files.

Comment: @Aristos, this is may look similar question but I am asking about HTML report and the answer you supplied as duplicate is about files. I have no report files, this is a report generated from html and on Response.Flush() it is been downloaded as document.

Comment: @Tabu.Net Is the same - you can not do it, you can not send multiple headers the one after the other for multiple files download. There is some way if you search it on the internet, but not on a loop. Also browser do not allow multiple documents to download at ones with out warning - asking the user. - the answer on the same question, can solve your issue too...